# How can I convert this from jQuery to standard javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know how to do this with standard javascript not jQuery.

```
$('form table img').click(function(){
    $('form table img').removeClass('selected')
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

I have an html document that cannot be modified and it has the following:

```
<form action="#">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/sunny.png" alt="Sunny" title="Sunny"></td>
            <td><img src="img/cloudy_snow.png" alt="Clouds with Snow" title="Cloudy with Snow"></td>
            <td><img src="img/sunny_cloudy.png" alt="Sunny with Clouds" title="Sunny with Clouds"></td>
            <td><img src="img/sunny_snow.png" alt="Sunny with Snow" title="Sunny with Snow"></td>
            <td><img src="img/thunderstorm.png" alt="Thunderstorm" title="Thunderstorm"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And I need to be able to get which image was clicked and add the class selected to it.

Comment: Do you realize, that you're asking for a whole plug-in?

Comment: '*Similar*' how? What, precisely, do you want to do? Where did your own attempt fail? What went wrong? And, seriously, two up-votes?

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this yet? do you have your attempted code? this smells like a work request (as is)

Comment: check some javascript native function by open the browser console, then input document.get****('anything'), and see the suggestion, read some documents, you'll learn it fast I guarantee :).

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ should help you. @DavidThomas Seven downvotes, seriously.

Comment: In your html code does not appear any a tag or tab-links class!

Comment: If the document cannot be modified, how do you plan to execute the future plain JS? If you want a plugin/extension for your favorite browser, then jQuery might still work. If you want to run this in the dev console, jQuery will still work, you just need to include it.

Comment: Ckeck my answer with the new demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) the  [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v7n6m1so/1/)

```
function addfunction(){
    link.forEach( function(e){
        e.classList.remove('selected');
    });

    this.classList.add('selected');
}

var link = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("form img"));

link.forEach(function(e){
    e.addEventListener("click",addfunction,false);
});
```

Comment: [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) only returns the first match.

Comment: then use `document.querySelectorall`

Comment: @Tambo with QSA, your answer is wrong. You would need to iterate the node list

Comment: That would need totally different handling. How about jQuery being more or less cross-browser?

Comment: Looks better now, though not very cross-browser. Can't remove the down-vote though (because I didn't vote down).

Comment: This works as I need it to... although I figured it out on my own before I saw this

Answer (score 3):

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".tab-links a"), function(x) {
    x.addEventListener("click", function() {
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".tab-links a"), function(y) {
            x.classList.remove("selected");
        });
        this.classList.add("selected");
    }, false);
});
```

Using the classList object, you need to iterate, attach the event, and re-iterate to remove instances of the class `selected`